# 同じ数同士線で結んだとき、交点ができるか否かの判定について

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

ary1 = [1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
を考えることにします。
1と1を上側で結んで、
2と2を上側で結んで、
3と3を上側で結んだとき
（無理やり結んだ曲線を交差させないかぎり）
交点は0個です。

一方
ary2 = [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1]
を考えることにします。
1と1を上側で結んで、
2と2を上側で結んで、
3と3を上側で結んだとき
交点は1個でできます。

このように、
ary の中に1～nまでの数字が2個ずつあり、
同じ数字同士上側で結んだとき、
交点ができるか否かの判定をするには
どうすればいいでしょうか？
（どうもあみだくじのようにはいかない…。）
考え方でもよいので教えてください。

Comment: 基本的にカッコの[マッチングの問題](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491125/push-and-pop-operation-using-stack-on-string)と同じだと思います。

Comment: @manyama さん。いつもアルゴリズムの問題、楽しく見ています。２個ずつじゃなくて３個以上を許したらどうなるか、配列が２次元、３次元になったらどうなるか、というお題で解いていただけると嬉しいです。プリント基板の配線問題に似ているのかなと思っています。

Comment: @Kenji Noguchi さん。1次元なら区間ですが、2次元なら直方形の頂点（計4個）で、3次元なら直方体の頂点（計8個）で囲む感じになるのでしょうか？

Comment: @manyama さん。すみません、３次元は問題として成り立ちそうにないです。もう少し考えてから質問として投稿しますね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BLUEPIXYさんが貼られた[括弧のマッチングの例](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30491125/2818869)と同様に、スタックを使った方法で書いてみました。

```
def test_intersect(arr)
    arr.inject([]) do |stack,item|
        stack.last == item ? stack[0..-2] : stack << item
    end == []
end
```

括弧の場合は閉じ括弧があるのでスタックの一番上を見るだけで打ち切り判定ができるのですが、今回の場合1回目なのか2回目なのかわからないので、とりあえず打ち切りなしで実装しました。

なんとなく `inject()` を使いましたが、普通のループで書いた方が効率はいいのかな。

Comment: end == [] を見たとき、何のことかわからなかったが、test_intersect(arr) がarr.inject([]){|stack, item| stack.last == item ? stack[0..-2] : stack << item} == [] の一行で書けるということを表していることにようやく気がつきました。

Comment: @Manyama 流石に仕事だったらこんなトリッキーな書き方は避けますが、半分お遊びということで。

Answer (score 2):

BLUEPIXY さんがおっしゃっているように、交点があるかどうかの判定は、入れ子状態になっているかどうかの判定に等しいと思います。

あまり洗練されてないですが、アルゴリズムはこんな感じになると思います。

```
def find_matched(arr,i)
  next_index=i+1
  while next_index && next_index < arr.length
    return next_index + 1 if arr[i] == arr[next_index]
    next_index = find_matched(arr,next_index)
  end
  nil
end

def test_intersect(arr)
  i=0
  while i && i < arr.length do
    i=find_matched(arr,i)
  end
  i == arr.length
end

test_intersect([1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1])
# => true
test_intersect([1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1])
# => false
test_intersect([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3])
# => false
test_intersect([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
# => true
```

Comment: 素早い回答ありがとうございます。p test_intersect( ) を実行すると答えが出ました。

Comment: @Manyama テストケースに漏れがあったので、修正しました。