# 同じ数同士左から順に線で結んだとき、交点ができるか否かの判定について

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

昨日質問した
[同じ数同士線で結んだとき、交点ができるか否かの判定について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20208/%E5%90%8C%E3%81%98%E6%95%B0%E5%90%8C%E5%A3%AB%E7%B7%9A%E3%81%A7%E7%B5%90%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D-%E4%BA%A4%E7%82%B9%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E5%90%A6%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E5%88%A4%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
の一般化を考えてみました。

ary1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
を考えることにします。
1と1を左から順番に飛ばさず上側で結びます。
同様に2と2を、3と3を飛ばさず上側で結びます。
（無理やり結んだ曲線を交差させないかぎり）
交点は0個です。

一方
ary2 = [1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
を考えることにします。
ary1 で行った操作を行うと
交点ができます。

このように、
ary の中に1～nまでの数字がk個ずつあり、
同じ数字同士左から順番に飛ばさず上側で結んだとき、
交点ができるか否かの判定をするには
どうすればいいでしょうか？

とりあえず、
[同じ数同士線で結んだとき、交点ができるか否かの判定について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20208/%E5%90%8C%E3%81%98%E6%95%B0%E5%90%8C%E5%A3%AB%E7%B7%9A%E3%81%A7%E7%B5%90%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D-%E4%BA%A4%E7%82%B9%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8B%E5%90%A6%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AE%E5%88%A4%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
のunarist さんの回答を元に以下のようなコードを書いてみました。

```
def test_intersect(ary, n, k)
  c_ary = Array.new(n, 0)
  stack = []
  ary.each{|i|
    if stack.last == i && c_ary[i - 1] == k - 1
      stack.pop
    else
      c_ary[i - 1] += 1
      stack << i if stack.last != i
    end
  }
  stack == []
end

p test_intersect([1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1], 3, 2)
p test_intersect([1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1], 3, 2)
p test_intersect([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1], 3, 3)
p test_intersect([1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1], 3, 3)
p test_intersect([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1], 3, 4)
p test_intersect([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1], 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

残っている片割れの数だけ余分に積むようにすれば、`c_ary` でカウントする必要はなくなりますね。
<sub>（そしてまたワンライナーに変形可能に）</sub>

```
def test_intersect(ary, n, k)
  stack = []
  ary.each{|item|
    if stack.last == item
      stack.pop
    else
      stack.concat(Array.new(k - 1, item))
    end
  }
  stack == []
end
```

Comment: ary.inject([]){|stack, item| stack.last == item ? stack[0..-2] : stack.concat(Array.new(k - 1, item))} == [] ということですね。

Comment: そして、c_ary でカウントする必要はなくなるということは、n も使わなくてすみますね。